# Groovy Spock File test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm about to start learning spock and I'm trying some basic stuff.
I want to check File's: exist() and getText() functionality
So I wrote the following test:

```
class MyTestSpec extends Specification {
  def "test file"() {
    given:
       def mockFile = Mock(File,constructorArgs :["./doesNotExist.txt"])
       mockFile.exists() >>  true
       mockFile.getText() >> "sampleText"

    when:
       def res = ""
       if(mockFile.exists()) {
          res = mockFile.getText()
       }

    then:
       "sampleText" == res
        1 * mockFile.exists()
        1 * mockFile.getText()
    }
}
```

This fails on:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * mockFile.getText()   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

When I comment the 'verifications' in 'then' block, I get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)    at
>   groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.(CharsetToolkit.java:69)    at
>   MyTestSpec.Test Existing Resource(MyTestSpec.groovy:83)

So my question is: How Exactly I can organize my test? Why does it assume that getText should not be called?

I'm using groovy 2.4 and spock 1.0

Comment: It seems that mocking an instance of `File` class might be non trivial. The code you provided is also missing testing method.

Comment: Thanks, testing method is added (its a copy-paste typo :) ) But the question still remains open...

Comment: I don't separate the invocation count from the stubbing so not sure if that works or not, but I have run into a similar null pointer issue and found the solution to be: `1 * mockFile.getProperty('text') >> 'sampleText'` - not sure why but in some cases spock or groovy does not like mocking property-style calls.

Comment: Also, as an alternative, you can test file behavior using the JUnit `@Rule TemporaryFolder` mechanism - spock tests are JUnit tests.

Comment: @cjstehno, this rather not a problem of property-style, but mocking groovy MOP methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution will be:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib:3.1') 
@Grab('org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.3') 

import spock.lang.*

class MyTestSpec extends Specification {
  def "test file"() {
    given:
       def mockFile = GroovyMock(File, constructorArgs :["./doesNotExist.txt"])

    when:
       def res = ""
       if(mockFile.exists()) {
          res = mockFile.getText()
       }

    then:
       "sampleText" == res
        1 * mockFile.exists() >> true
        1 * mockFile.getText() >> "sampleText"
    }
}
```

On of the problems is creating a mock. Because of a dynamic nature of groovy some functionality - e.g. [`getText()`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ResourceGroovyMethods.java#L589) method for `File` class - is added at runtime. It requires mocks to be constructed in a different way. Have a look at spock [mock implementation enum](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/MockImplementation.java#L36) and extract:

> An implementation specifically targeting Groovy callers. Supports mocking of dynamic methods, constructors, static methods, and "magic" mocking of all objects of a particular type.

The second problem is defining mock behavior and verifying the interactions. When you both mock and stub it must happen in the same interaction (here, in `then` block), [here](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) is he relevant part of the docs.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! It works indeed, But I still have no idea why. It really could be great to understand why does it work.

Comment: @MarkBramnik, added the explanation.